# Tight fit in horizontal diagram generated with forest

Tags: diagrams, trees, forest

I use the forest package to create a diagram similar to the one below. Is there any chance to reduce the distance between B5 and B6? I would prefer, if B6 and its subtree could be moved up. I have played around with the options `l`, `s`, `l sep`, `s sep` and `fit` without success so far. Actually I thought the default value `fit=tight` should do the job, but it does not...

[image]

Source for example diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={fit=tight}
[A, grow'=east
[B1,
[B2,
[B3,
[B4,
[B5,
[B6, grow'=east,
[C, grow'=east,
[D1, for tree={grow=north},
[D2,
[D3
]]]
[E1, for tree={grow=south},
[E2
]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Source for full diagram:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

% Document
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={anchor=center}
[FB, grow'=east
[BJ$_X$
[BJ$_Y$
[BJ$_Z$
[BJ$_X$
[BJ$_Y$
[BJ$_Z$, grow'=east
[F, grow'=east
[LLJ$_X$, for tree={grow=north}
[LLJ$_Z$
[F, grow=east
[FT, for tree={grow=south}, [WMJ$_{ABD}$, [WM$_{ABD}$]]]
[ABD, for tree={grow=north}
[ULJ$_X$
[ULJ$_Y$
[ULJ$_Z$
[F, grow=east
[FT, for tree={grow=south}, [WMJ$_{THO}$, [WM$_{THO}$]]]
[THO, for tree={grow=north}
[F, grow'=east
[F, grow'=east
[LNJ$_X$, [LNJ$_Y$, [LNJ$_Z$, [HEA, for tree={grow=north}, [EP]]]]]
[SJ$_{L,X}$, for tree={grow=south}, [SJ$_{L,Y}$, [SJ$_{L,Z}$, [UPA$_L$, [EJ$_{L,Z}$, [LOA$_L$, [EP]]]]]]]
]
[SJ$_{R,X}$, for tree={grow=south}, [SJ$_{R,Y}$, [SJ$_{R,Z}$, [UPA$_R$, [EJ$_{R,Z}$, [LOA$_R$, [EP]]]]]]]
]]]]]]]]]]
[PEL, for tree={grow=south}
[F, grow=south
[HJ$_{L,X}$, [HJ$_{L,Y}$, [HJ$_{L,Z}$, [THI$_L$, [KJ$_{L,Z}$, [SHA$_L$, [AJ$_{L,X}$, [AJ$_{L,X}$, [AJ$_{L,X}$, [F, grow'=east, [COPJ$_{L,X}$, for tree={grow=north}, [COPJ$_{L,Y}$, [COPJ$_{L,Z}$, [COP$_L$]]]], [FOO$_L$, [EP]]]]]]]]]]]]
[HJ$_{R,X}$, [HJ$_{R,Y}$, [HJ$_{R,Z}$,, [THI$_R$, [KJ$_{R,Z}$, [SHA$_R$, [AJ$_{R,X}$, [AJ$_{R,X}$, [AJ$_{R,X}$, [F, grow'=east, [COPJ$_{R,X}$, for tree={grow=north}, [COPJ$_{R,Y}$, [COPJ$_{R,Z}$, [COP$_R$]]]], [FOO$_R$, [EP]]]]]]]]]]]]
]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `for tree={fit=tight,l sep=-30mm}` help?

Comment: Using l sep=-30mm, will reduce the longest line between B5 and B6, but it won't reduce the other lines any further ... at least not in my tests.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. `l sep=-30mm` works fine for the given example. Unfortunately not for my actual diagram (I added the source to the question). So probably I have to play around with `l sep` for each node?

Comment: You can increase it to `l sep=-200mm`... Maybe it creates other line problems. But do you really need such big diagram? I

Comment: Well, I was able to tune the distances by setting `l sep+=5mm` for the F nodes and `l sep=-300mm` for the others. Thank you again! If you put your comment in an answer, I am happy to accept it :)

Comment: I think the constant changes in the direction of growth confuse Forest. However, I'm not sure whether it is expected that it gets quite so confused quite so quickly ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure this is much of an improvement. However, it is a lot clearer what is going on and the code is considerably less cluttered. It is also slightly more compact (both width and height/depth are smaller than in the OP's solution). Whether any of this is of any importance is, of course, another matter.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  fixedBase/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, text=white},
  prismaticJoint/.style={draw},
  revoluteJoint/.style={draw, rounded corners=2mm},
  rigidLink/.style={draw, color=blue, fill=blue, text=white},
  fixedTranslation/.style={draw, fill=gray},
  fixedRotation/.style={draw, fill=gray, rounded corners=2mm},
  springDamperElement/.style={draw, circle, color=blue, fill=blue, text=white},
  fork/.style={draw, circle, color=red, fill=red, text=white},
  endpoint/.style={draw, fill=black, text=white},
}
\newsavebox\treelegend
\setbox0=\hbox{% solution from Steven B. Segletes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366710/
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, column 2/.style={text height=3.5mm, text depth=3.5mm, text width=40mm}]
    {%
      |[fixedBase]| F8 & Fixed base \\
      |[prismaticJoint]| PJ & Prismatic joint \\
      |[revoluteJoint]| RJ & Revolute joint \\
      |[rigidLink]| RL & Rigid link \\
      |[fixedTranslation]| FT & Fixed translation \\
      |[springDamperElement]| SD & Spring-damper element \\
      |[fork]| F & Fork \\
      |[endpoint]| EP & Endpoint \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\savebox\treelegend{\copy0}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
  fork/.style={
    /tikz/fork,
    before computing xy={for children={l'+=8mm}},
  },
  for tree={
    anchor=center
  },
  before computing xy={
    for tree={l'=9mm},
  }
  [FB, fixedBase, grow'=east, anchor=east
    [BJ$_X$, prismaticJoint, for tree={grow=north}
    [BJ$_Y$, prismaticJoint
    [BJ$_Z$, prismaticJoint
    [BJ$_X$, revoluteJoint
    [BJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint
    [BJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint, grow'=east
    [F, fork, grow'=east, before computing xy={for children={l'+=5mm}}
    [LLJ$_X$, revoluteJoint, for tree={grow=north}
            [LLJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint
            [F, fork, grow=east
            [FT, fixedTranslation, for tree={grow=south}
              [WMJ$_{ABD}$, prismaticJoint
                [SD, springDamperElement, before computing xy={l'=0pt, s'=15mm}]
                [EP, endpoint, before computing xy={l=10mm, s'=0pt}]
              ]
            ]
            [ABD, rigidLink, for tree={grow=north}
            [ULJ$_X$, revoluteJoint
            [ULJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint
            [ULJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint
            [F, fork, grow=east
            [FT, fixedTranslation, for tree={grow=south}
              [WMJ$_{THO}$, prismaticJoint
                [SD, springDamperElement, before computing xy={l'=0pt, s'=15mm}]
                [EP, endpoint, before computing xy={l=10mm, s'=0pt}]
              ]
            ]
            [THO, rigidLink, for tree={grow=north}
            [F, fork, grow'=east, before computing xy={for children={l'+=10mm}}
            [F, fork, grow'=east
            [LNJ$_X$, revoluteJoint
              [LNJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint
                [LNJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint
                  [HEA, rigidLink, for tree={grow=north}
                    [EP, endpoint]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
            [SJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint, for tree={grow=south}
              [SJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint
                [SJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                  [UPA$_L$, rigidLink
                    [EJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                      [LOA$_L$, rigidLink
                        [EP, endpoint]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [SJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint, for tree={grow=south}
            [SJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint
              [SJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                [UPA$_R$, rigidLink
                  [EJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                    [LOA$_R$, rigidLink
                      [EP, endpoint]
                    ]
                   ]
                 ]
               ]
             ]
           ]
    ]]]]]]]]]
    ]
    [PEL, rigidLink, for tree={grow=south}
      [F, fork, grow=south, before packing={s sep'+=5mm}, before computing xy={for children={l'-=5mm}}
        [HJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint
          [HJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint
            [HJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint
              [THI$_L$, rigidLink
                [KJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                  [SHA$_L$, rigidLink
                    [AJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint
                      [AJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint
                        [AJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                          [F, fork, grow'=east
                            [COPJ$_{L,X}$, prismaticJoint, for tree={grow=north}
                              [COPJ$_{L,Y}$, prismaticJoint
                                [COPJ$_{L,Z}$, prismaticJoint
                                  [EP, endpoint]
                                ]
                              ]
                            ]
                            [FOO$_L$, rigidLink
                              [EP, endpoint]
                            ]
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [HJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint
          [HJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint
            [HJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint
              [THI$_R$, rigidLink
                [KJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                  [SHA$_R$, rigidLink
                    [AJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint
                      [AJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint
                        [AJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint
                          [F, fork, grow'=east
                            [COPJ$_{R,X}$, prismaticJoint, for tree={grow=north}
                              [COPJ$_{R,Y}$, prismaticJoint
                                [COPJ$_{R,Z}$, prismaticJoint
                                  [EP, endpoint]
                                ]
                              ]
                            ]
                            [FOO$_R$, rigidLink
                              [EP, endpoint]
                            ]
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]]]]]]]]
  ]
  \node [anchor=north west] at (current bounding box.north west) {\usebox{\treelegend}};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: which-way tree]

Comment: @JotWe I've also left a message in the Forest chat room as I'm not clear whether it is expected that this much manual intervention is needed i.e. that Forest gets confused very quickly. But I think Forest's author is not around just at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thank you Bobyandbob and Tina for providing the initial hint. The option `l sep` was the key. Here is the code and diagram I finally came up with. I had to use some `before computing xy`, but I like the result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
fixedBase/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, text=white},
prismaticJoint/.style={draw},
revoluteJoint/.style={draw, rounded corners=2mm},
rigidLink/.style={draw, color=blue, fill=blue, text=white},
fixedTranslation/.style={draw, fill=gray},
fixedRotation/.style={draw, fill=gray, rounded corners=2mm},
springDamperElement/.style={draw, circle, color=blue, fill=blue, text=white},
fork/.style={draw, circle, color=red, fill=red, text=white},
endpoint/.style={draw, fill=black, text=white},
}

\begin{forest}
for tree={anchor=center}
[FB, fixedBase, l sep=-300mm, grow'=east,
[FB, fixedBase, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=160mm}, [Fixed base, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[PJ, prismaticJoint, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=150mm}, [Prismatic joint, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[RJ, revoluteJoint, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=140mm}, [Revolute joint, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[RL, rigidLink, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=130mm}, [Rigid link, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[FT, fixedTranslation, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=120mm}, [Fixed translation, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[SD, springDamperElement, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=110mm}, [Spring-damper element, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[F, fork, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=100mm}, [Fork, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[EP, endpoint, edge'={}, grow'=east, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=90mm}, [Endpoint, edge'={}, anchor=west, before computing xy={l=5mm, s=0}]],
[BJ$_X$, prismaticJoint, l sep=-300mm, for tree={grow=north}, before computing xy={l=12mm, s=0}, 
[BJ$_Y$, prismaticJoint, l sep=-300mm, 
[BJ$_Z$, prismaticJoint, l sep=-300mm, 
[BJ$_X$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, 
[BJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, 
[BJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, grow'=east,
[F, fork, grow'=east,
[LLJ$_X$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, for tree={grow=north},
[LLJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm,
[F, fork, grow=east,
[FT, fixedTranslation, for tree={grow=south}, [WMJ$_{ABD}$, prismaticJoint, [SD, springDamperElement, before computing xy={l=0, s=15mm}], [EP, endpoint, before computing xy={l=10mm, s=0}]]],
[ABD, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, for tree={grow=north},
[ULJ$_X$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm,
[ULJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm,
[ULJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm,
[F, fork, grow=east,
[FT, fixedTranslation, for tree={grow=south}, [WMJ$_{THO}$, prismaticJoint, [SD, springDamperElement, before computing xy={l=0, s=15mm}], [EP, endpoint, before computing xy={l=10mm, s=0}]]],
[THO, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, for tree={grow=north},
[F, fork, l sep+=15mm, grow'=east,
[F, fork, l sep+=5mm, grow'=east,
[LNJ$_X$, revoluteJoint, [LNJ$_Y$, revoluteJoint, [LNJ$_Z$, revoluteJoint, [HEA, rigidLink, for tree={grow=north}, [EP, endpoint]]]]],
[SJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint, for tree={grow=south}, [SJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint, [SJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint, [UPA$_L$, rigidLink, [EJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint, [LOA$_L$, rigidLink, [EP, endpoint]]]]]]],
],
[SJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint, for tree={grow=south}, [SJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint, [SJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint, [UPA$_R$, rigidLink, [EJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint, [LOA$_R$, rigidLink, [EP, endpoint]]]]]]],
]]]]]]]]]],
[PEL, rigidLink, for tree={grow=south},
[F, fork, grow=south,
[HJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [HJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [HJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [THI$_L$, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, [KJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [SHA$_L$, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{L,X}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{L,Y}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{L,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [F, fork, grow'=east, [COPJ$_{L,X}$, prismaticJoint, for tree={grow=north}, [COPJ$_{L,Y}$, prismaticJoint, [COPJ$_{L,Z}$, prismaticJoint, [EP, endpoint]]]], [FOO$_L$, rigidLink, [EP, endpoint]]]]]]]]]]]],
[HJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [HJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [HJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [THI$_R$, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, [KJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [SHA$_R$, rigidLink, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{R,X}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{R,Y}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [AJ$_{R,Z}$, revoluteJoint, l sep=-300mm, [F, fork, grow'=east, [COPJ$_{R,X}$, prismaticJoint, for tree={grow=north}, [COPJ$_{R,Y}$, prismaticJoint, [COPJ$_{R,Z}$, prismaticJoint, [EP, endpoint]]]], [FOO$_R$, rigidLink, [EP, endpoint]]]]]]]]]]]],
]]]]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you could prune this quite a bit. `l sep=-300mm` doesn't make much sense. I would rename `fork`, if I were you, to avoid confusion with `forked edge`. I mean, technically, `fork` is fine. But I would find it potentially confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with you that it might be confusing, but these are predefined terms from a modeling library I used.

Comment: I was more concerned about `l sep=-300mm`. Since `l sep` is the minimum separation permitted between levels, what would this mean? That the next level always precede its parent by at least 0.3m?

Comment: Yes, the approach is quite 'hacky' and probably just tricks the placing algorithm. Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: To be honest, using Forest this way is just an effective way to make your compilation much slower than it would otherwise be. If you are going to place everything manually, using Forest is just going to be an exercise in frustration. You are specifying `grow'=east` when you actually want nodes to appear to the west. Then you are relocating everything again later. This is not a tree and Forest isn't a good choice to draw it.  You are even creating the legend as part of the tree - why? It is just a slow, verbose way of making what is basically a matrix or tabular.

Comment: When I implemented the graph, it was very convenient to use the syntax of the forest package in order to get the general form. In a second step I started to care about the look and placed some of the nodes manually to make it more compact. The legend is definitely a pretty dirty hack, but because I use it as a standalone figure, compilation time is not that important.

Comment: The semantics of `l sep`: assuming `grow=south` at a node, its descendants will be pushed down if they stick up into the `l sep` high and "infinitely" wide rectangle between the node and its children. Obviously, `l sep` works for any direction of growth, but wording the semantics in general is painful ;-)

Comment: The solution presented here (setting `l sep` to a large negative dimension) is how I'd do it. The only adverse side effect I can imagine could be TeX arithmetic overflow. For that to happen, the minimum `l` coordinate achieved by descendants plus (negative) `l sep` should be less than the smallest allowed dimension,`-16383.99999pt`.)

Comment: I could, in principle, clutter the option space by introducing a boolean option `ignore l sep` or such (the implementation would be trivial), but I don't think it's worth it.