# How can a matrix of nodes be saved into a box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, boxes, matrices, tikz-matrix

Normally, it is possible to save a `tikzpicture` into a box for later use. Indeed, this is one recommended strategy for the use of one `tikzpicture` within another: the use of the box avoids the dangers of nesting `tikzpicture`s.

Can this be done if the `tikzpicture` consists of a `matrix of nodes`?

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [matrix of nodes]
    {
      a & b \\
      c & d \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usebox\mybox
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.185 }

? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why, but sometimes, the `tikz` needs to be saved in a temporary box, which *then* can be saved in a more permanent way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [matrix of nodes]
    { 
      a & b \\
      c & d \\
    };
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\sbox\mybox{\copy0}
here is \usebox\mybox 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realise it was a somewhat blasphemous request :-).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366713/

Answer (score 6):

This is the good old catcode problem with `&` as a column separator.  The `\sbox` macro reads the contents of the box as an argument which makes it impossible for TikZ to scan for the ampersand.  You have several possibilities to get around that:

1. Use `ampersand replacement`, no catcode changes required on the TikZ side.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \begin{document}
   \newsavebox\mybox
   \sbox\mybox{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
       {
         a \& b \\
         c \& d \\
       };
     \end{tikzpicture}%
   }
   \usebox\mybox
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use `\setbox\mybox=\hbox{...}` instead of `\sbox`.  The box contents are not read as an argument and everything is fine.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \begin{document}
   \newsavebox\mybox
   \setbox\mybox=\hbox{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \matrix [matrix of nodes]
       {
         a & b \\
         c & d \\
       };
     \end{tikzpicture}%
   }
   \usebox\mybox
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Basically, the same reason as 2. but more LaTeX-y.  Use `lrbox`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \begin{document}
   \newsavebox\mybox
   \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \matrix [matrix of nodes]
       {
         a & b \\
         c & d \\
       };
     \end{tikzpicture}%
   \end{lrbox}
   \usebox\mybox
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Fix up `\sbox` to rescan the tokens it is passed.  This is probably one of the few valid uses of `\scantokens`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
   \makeatletter
   \long\def\sbox#1#2{\setbox#1\hbox{%
       \color@setgroup\scantokens{#2}\color@endgroup}}
   \makeatother
   \begin{document}
   \newsavebox\mybox
   \sbox\mybox{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \matrix [matrix of nodes]
       {
         a & b \\
         c & d \\
       };
     \end{tikzpicture}%
   }
   \usebox\mybox
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Yours is a most excellent answer.